# What am I missing when setting up reverse DNS?

Tags: networking, mysql-replication, reverse-dns, powerdns, solusvm

I'm setting up rDNS for use with a SolusVM server. I used PowerDNS on two servers for a slave and a master, and set up the MySQL replication successfully. When viewing the MySQL records table, I see the SOA, NS, and PTR records all there.

I've created two A records (rdns1.example.com, rdns2.example.com) and pointed them to the master and slave respectively.

I updated the IP reverse DNS nameservers on arin.net to point to the rdns1.example.com and rdns2.example.com

If I run 'host 146.71.84.4', it returns:

```
 Host 4.84.71.146.in-addr.arpa not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

If I run 'dig -x 146.71.84.4', it returns:

```
 ; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u10-Debian <<>> 146.71.84.4
 ;; global options: +cmd
 ;; Got answer:
 ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 41971
 ;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

 ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
 ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
 ;; QUESTION SECTION:
 ;146.71.84.4.                   IN      A

 ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
 .                       73327   IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2017041600 1800 900 604800 86400

 ;; Query time: 14 msec
 ;; SERVER: 50.116.35.5#53(50.116.35.5)
 ;; WHEN: Sun Apr 16 09:07:33 UTC 2017
 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 115
```

Comment: The dig output looks to be from that command but without `-x`

Comment: Neither server appears to be responding at all, is it running? Firewall?

Comment: I don't think I mentioned it in the question, the IPs for the PowerDNS master/server are 146.71.84.43 and 146.71.84.44 respectively if that was your question. No firewalls and they're running.

Comment: Then how come neither of them responds at all?

Comment: Not responding to a ping? That's odd, it's responding to both my home computer and online ping tools

Comment: Not responding to DNS queries

Comment: I've restarted it with a monitored start and it looks like everything is OK. Maybe try again

Comment: Looks good. I believe that solved your problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither nameserver was responding to queries at all.

Ensure that the nameserver software is running (check logs if not starting) and that no firewall is interfering.

Comment: You are amazing! The issue was multiple launch= statements in the powerdns config preventing it from running correctly/at all. SolusVM rdns guide doesn't mention that you need to replace it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Just for the record: You can launch multiple backends with one launch statement. https://doc.powerdns.com/md/authoritative/settings/#launch PowerDNS will exhaust each backend for resources pertaining to the queries it gets in the order in which they are specified there.